# PHP login form does not read user level

Tags: php

I want to make a login form which can be used by normal users and admins. The code should tell the difference between normal users and admins and based on it, start a new session after user is logged in (admin or user session). In my database table, I added "level" column which should determine if user is an admin or not (for ex.: if the user level is 3, then they are admin).

Here is my `login.php` file:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'database.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (!$username or !$password) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    } else {
        $execution = "SELECT level FROM users WHERE name = '$username' AND password = '$password';";
        $result = mysqli_query($database, $execution);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 3) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        } 
    }
}
```

The code does not work because when I try to log in with a user that has LEVEL 3 in database, it still starts the normal user session and does not go through the `elseif` statement that I wrote above. How do I fix this? Maybe I am doing this completely wrong and there is another way to do this admin/user login thing?

Btw: I do understand that I'm storing passwords in plain text here, but right now I am only experimenting with the code and do not plan to upload it to a website.

Comment: You're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: Read the bottom part of the post, I am not uploading it anywhere yet, although I will make sure to protect it from SQL injection when I will.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows($result) == 3 is verifying the total rows returned, is not verifying the level value.

Comment: You also can't output after an `exit`, put the string in that function call if you want it returned.. although you are redirecting so you likely won't see it anyway.

Comment: The thing about doing not writing proper code from the start, is that you end up doing the work many times over, and doing it this way teaches bad habits, even if it isn't supposed to be uploaded anywhere. Learn to do it right from the start, you'll thank yourself in the future for doing it right from the start.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @user3783243 Even so, result is an object and can't be printed like that.

Comment: I'm glad @Qirel said it because I'd have to go off on a rant.

Comment: Using echo after exit was unintended and I accidentally wrote it there.. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you aren’t checking the user’s level at all.

Your first if block only checks if the result has one row.

Also, you should use prepared statements to prevent injection.

This is the correct code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include_once 'database.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (!$username or !$password) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    } else {
        $execution = mysqli_prepare($database, "SELECT level FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?;";
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($execution, "ss", $username, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($execution);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($execution);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            session_start();
            if ($row['level'] == 1) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                header('Location: login.php');
            }
            elseif ($row['level'] == 3) {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            exit();
            echo "$result";
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code updated.

You need to get the value of level in order to apply the permissions.

```
session_start();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){

         if($row['level'] == 1){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
         }elseif( $row['level'] == 3){
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            header('Location: login.php');
            exit();
        }

   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need a while loop if you only expect one row, which you only should get from a login anyways